# GRASS r.stream* modules failing to install in Ubuntu

Tags: grass-7.0

I tried to install several r.stream* modules within GRASS GIS 7.0.4, running under Ubuntu 14.04. Specifically, after trying to install `r.stream.order` from `g.extension`, output console returns "undefined reference" errors in libgrass_vector.7.0.4.so. These are the first four, among many:

> ```
> /usr/lib/grass70/lib/libgrass_vector.7.0.4.so:
> undefined reference to `OGRGeometryTypeToName@GDAL_1.8'
> /usr/lib/grass70/lib/libgrass_vector.7.0.4.so:
> undefined reference to `OGR_G_GetY@GDAL_1.8'
> /usr/lib/grass70/lib/libgrass_vector.7.0.4.so:
> undefined reference to `OGR_F_SetGeometry@GDAL_1.8'
> /usr/lib/grass70/lib/libgrass_vector.7.0.4.so:
> undefined reference to `OGR_G_GetGeometryType@GDAL_1.8'
> ```

I googled these messages but couldn't find helpful advise. What could be the problem?